# Can you create this shadowed gradient style line using CSS3?

Tags: html, css

[Here's a picture of exactly what I'm trying to produce.](http://i39.tinypic.com/izc22t.jpg)

I've been able to style a `<hr />` using SVG as the background image to create this effect, but would like to be able to produce the same thing using CSS3 I've but have been having trouble.

I was wondering if any CSS gurus out there might know a way to achieve the same thing or if it's not really possible w/ pure CSS?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The image link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create the effect with three layers, two backgrounds with alpha opacity. One that starts at top and stops at the middle, another that starts at middle at ends at bottom, and one background with a slice of the [image](http://i41.tinypic.com/omwky.gif) repeated in the y axis.

I follow this url for the layer tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

The html code, only works in Chrome, substitute/overwrite the property "-webkit-gradient" for the specific broser:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .gradient {
    width:76px;
    height:200px;
    border:0;
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 50%, from(rgba(192,192,192,1)), to(rgba(192,192,192,0))),
                    -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 50%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(192,192,192,0)), to(rgba(192,192,192,1))),
                    url(http://i41.tinypic.com/omwky.gif);
    background-repeat:repeat-y,repeat-y, repeat-y;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <hr class="gradient"/>
</body>
</html>
```